# How to make compound indexes in DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to create documents like

```
{
  age : 32,
  name : "Alexander"
}
```

And make queries like

```
select * from myColl where age=32 and name='Alexander'
```

So normally to make these queries efficient, I would have index with these two fields. 
How to achieve the same effect with document DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worry that this ask is a premature optimization but if you've already determined that you need to get better performance, then you can create another field that is a concatenation of those two fields. Since no one lives longer than 999 years, you can leading-zero-pad the age (so, 32 becomes the string '032') and concatenate the name after that. You'll have to build a similar string for your queries also.

What I've proposed above is a somewhat ugly work-around for the fact that DocumentDB has no native compound indexes. In practice, I've never needed it since I started working with DocumentDB, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your reply